# Change text in HTML that I'm grabbing from a text file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

What I'm doing is grabbing the HTML code for my header from a text file.

But once a User logs in I want it to say Welcome "Username" at the top, which is a dropdown to account settings, cart, etc...

So since I'm inserting the HTML into a DIV on page load, I don't actually have access to any of the elements inside in C#.

How would I go about doing this? Is there any way to access something like a (p id="name")'s inner text, after its loaded in from the text file?

Would like to do this with C# not JS please.

Edit: I have a work around for now, but I am still interested in better answers.

```c#
 headerText = headerText.Replace("::Username::", Session["Username"] as string);
```

Here is my code for grabbing the HTML and pasting it in.

```
string headerText = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/global/header.html"));
        string footerText = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/global/footer.html"));

        headerText = headerText.Replace("::Username::", Session["Username"] as string);

        divHeader.InnerHtml = headerText;
        divFooter.InnerHtml = footerText;
```

To be more clear, is there anyway to access something like

```
 <asp:Panel ID="panelAccount" runat="server">
```

which is stored in another HTML file.

Comment: google.com will get u the answer

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done similar work in C# earlier, I use HTMLAgilityPack for doing this kind of works. Later I start using Anglesharp since it has a very good CSS selector based support.

Try [anglesharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) and you can modify the HTML tag like you do in jQuery.

Comment: First of all Adrian, thank you for providing me with an actual response. And thank you for not being abusive and condescending by down voting without giving a reason why, like a lot of people seem to do on stack..
You truly are the only hope for this website.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I liked Adrians response, I found out a better way to do what I needed to do, I could do with a MasterPage. I definitely be using Adrians answer for a load of other things though so it still holds valid.

Then in the C# file associated with the master page you create a property like this.

```
 public Panel PanelAccount
    {
        get { return panelAccount; }
        set { panelAccount = value; }
    }
```

Then from the regular WebForm, you can call "PanelAccount" to access that property.

[Here is a tutorial for how to do that.](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/801325/access-master-page-controls-from-content-page-in-c)

Thanks for everyones downvotes with no inputs, you guys are stars!